# Galasoft MVVMlight creating issues while app certification in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 app that is ready for certification but i get an error saying that galasoft mvvm light was built using the debug mode so we cannot accept this.

Any solutions to this ?

Comment: How did you reference MVVM Light?

Comment: using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc

Comment: But did you download the source, install from NuGet, etc.?

Comment: Yup It was using NuGet packages and its in the respective Packages folder also